# How to convert a CString to a char in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

1. How to convert a CString to a char in C++ ?
2. Do i need to add any header if i use CString?
   Please hlp me with examples.

Comment: Is it possible that you help us first posting examples of what you have and you really want to do..?

Comment: What do you mean "convert CString to *a* char"? Do you perhaps mean, convert a CString to a C-style char* pointer to a \0-terminated char array string?

Comment: Hi acorbe, just a simple example like Dmitriy showed

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
CString test;
char  buffer[256];  
strcpy(buffer, LPCSTR(test));
```

2.

```
#include <atlstr.h>
CString s = "Hallo";
char *buffer;
buffer = s.GetBuffer();
```

Comment: 1. Copy to uninitialized var?
2. GetBuffer without ReleaseBuffer?

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, Do i need to add any header file for ur 1st answer, its showing red line in CString

Comment: this has ouch written all over it.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.80).aspx

Examples how to convert string properly

Comment: i didnt find any example there